# C# - How to pass string from WebBrowser back into a form

Tags: c#, .net

How can I read string from WebBrowser form into another form using C#?

Comment: And what have you tried?

Comment: I am now finding out is it possible?

Comment: Some more information about what you do, please.

Comment: Use session and pass it across the pages ... you need to anyways modify your question in case you need an appropriate answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the DOM. For example, if your WebBrowser shows a page with the following markup:

```
<div id="t">
    ....
</div>
```

You can receive its text just like you're doing it in JavaScript:

```
webBrowser.Document.GetElementById("t").InnerText
```